# Why is my perl split(), at all 3rd occurences of a space not working?

Tags: perl

I want to rewrite the text below by breaking it into three strings on a line. I read the text from a file as an array. Next I join all the elements of the array (4 lines) into a scalar variable. I then try to split the joined element at every third occurrence of a space.
My code is below.

```
open ($TMP, "< TTaaInLittler.txt") or die "open 'TTaaInLittler.txt: failed $! ($^E)";
my @alldata=<$TMP>;
my $oneline=join(" ", @alldata);
close$TMP;

my $i = 0;
my $n = 3;

my @oneline=split(" ", $oneline, 10) if !( ++$i % $n );
print @oneline;
```

The join() command seems to work because "`print $oneline`" prints all the text. Printing $oneline, however prints 4 lines. I was expecting one line. The split command does not seem to work, because "`print @oneline`" does not do anything; no error, no output.
Is ther a way out? Please help.

```
TTAA 58231 63741 99823 15423 17003 70152 07604 29517 50586 04381
08513 40758 16182 11524 30967 31964 00510 25094 41365 25503
20241 53562 10512 15419 68542 07540 10656 76156 11024 88123
76950 09548 77999 31313 47708 82318=
 
TTAA 58231 63741
99823 15423 17003
70152 07604 29517
50586 04381 08513
40758 16182 11524
30967 31964 00510
25094 41365 25503
20241 53562 10512
15419 68542 07540 
10656 76156 11024
88123 76950 09548
77999 31313 47708 
82318=
```

Comment: `perl -0777 -pe's/\s+/(++$n % 3)?" ":"\n"/eg' input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to break all input into words and then print every three words on a line

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use feature 'say';

die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not @ARGV;

# "Slurp" into a variable the file with the name given on the command line
my $content = do { local $/; <> };

my @words = split ' ', $content;

say join(' ', splice @words, 0, 3)  while @words;
```

This prints as desired for the given input file, when run as `scriptname.pl input-filename`.

---

A needed explanation follows.

Arguments given on the command line are in [@ARGV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@ARGV) in a Perl program.  So we first test whether `@ARGV` may be emtpy; if the user indeed didn't supply the needed argument (input filename here) there is nothing the program can do and we `die` (and exit in this case), with a succinct usage message.<sup>†</sup>

The file is read into a string in the `do` block. The "*input record separator*" ([`$/` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/))<sup>‡</sup> is localized to the block using [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29) and as it gets undefined the [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) then reads the whole file with the name in `@ARGV`, so the (first) one given on the command line. This is assigned to `$content` and we got our file.

Then [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) breaks that string by any whitespace using its idiomatic `' '` pattern, giving us the list of words in the file.

Finally, [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice) removes and returns the first three words, which are joined by space and printed on a line, and keeps doing that as long as there's anything in `@words`. (If there's not three elements in its target array it removes as many as there are, finally exhausting and emptying the array.)

All this can be fit in one statement but there is no reason for such acrobatics here.

More to the point, this can be done by using libraries.  We can read the file into a variable with [Path::Tiny::slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#slurp,-slurp_raw,-slurp_utf8), and process groups of elements using [List::MoreUtils::natatime](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#natatime-EXPR,-LIST) (n-at-a-time).

---

<sup>†</sup>  The `\n` at the end of the [die](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die) statement suppresses the  `... at program-name line 5.`, which is normally printed, since it wouldn't mean much here.  This is very rudimentary, and there are much better ways to provide for and handle user input.  See [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long)

<sup>‡</sup> Also see [this section in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Variables-related-to-filehandles)

Comment: Thanks @zdim. It looks like your concise code could do what I want. Can you guide me, I want to read the data from a file. I do not see how I can do that. Also this has to be eventually automated with different content every time, so running it on the command line is not my best option. On the command line, I guess the way to run it is "$0 perlscript inputfile". Please correct me.

Comment: Well, you run this as `perl scriptname.pl input-filename`. If you make the script executable then it's `scriptname.pl input-filename`, like it says. (The first line, with `die...`, is the usage message.) Then it is run out of a program the same way, just like any command runs out of a program.  Can use `system`, or `qx` (backticks), or -- better -- libraries for that, like `IPC::System::Simple`, `Capture::Tiny`, `IPC::Run`.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: So in a program that's supposed to run this you'd have `system(scriptname.pl $filename)...` (or using `qx`, or libraries), where that program gets the `$filename` whichever way it is meant to.  Do you know how to run external commands out of a program?  You run this script exactly the same way.

Comment: I added this information to the answer, below the code. Remember that the file need be executable (`chmod u+x scriptname` in linux) for this, or prepend `perl ...` to that.

Comment: Yes you are very clear. In the code, the line with "die ..." is not very clear on where the input data file comes. I am very familiar with running system commands in Perl.  I have run the code. It works perfectly. I really appreciate your time and effort. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba I just realized I somehow missed to respond to this comment, sorry.  Just edited the answer to add an explanation for that first line (`die ...`)

Answer (score 2):

Please investigate following code snippet for compliance with your problem.

NOTE: to read data from a file replace `<DATA>` with `<>`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my($num,$count) = (3,1);
my @array = split(' ', do { local $/; <DATA> });

print $_, ($count++ % $num) ? ' ': "\n" for @array;

__DATA__
TTAA 58231 63741 99823 15423 17003 70152 07604 29517 50586 04381
08513 40758 16182 11524 30967 31964 00510 25094 41365 25503
20241 53562 10512 15419 68542 07540 10656 76156 11024 88123
76950 09548 77999 31313 47708 82318=
```

Output

```
TTAA 58231 63741
99823 15423 17003
70152 07604 29517
50586 04381 08513
40758 16182 11524
30967 31964 00510
25094 41365 25503
20241 53562 10512
15419 68542 07540
10656 76156 11024
88123 76950 09548
77999 31313 47708
82318=
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, and `split` works fine. To understand your problem you should understand what your code actually does. First if you do.

```
my @alldata=<$TMP>;
```

then it reads the whole file in the array, but every line still contains a newline at the end.

Then you `join` every line with a space into one-string.

```
my $oneline=join(" ", @alldata);
```

But the newlines are not removed. If you for example have the array.

```
["foo\n", "bar\n", "baz\n"]
```

and then join this array with a space, you get the string.

```
"foo\n bar\n baz\n"
```

If you print this string, then sure, it will print over multiple lines. Because it still contains multiple lines. You could avoid this problem by chomping the array before you join it.

```
chomp @data;
my $str  = join " ", @data;
```

On top there is a special case when you use `split` with just a space. Then it is treated as `split /\s+/`. This means it not only split on a space character, it splits on all whitespace characters, and multiple of them at once.

Additionally, sometimes it is better to use a regex to remove newlines like this.

```
s/\r?\n// for @data;
```

By default, `chomp` removes a newline that is specific to your operting system. So on Linux it will remove only `\n` on Windows it removes `\r\n`. But if you work on cross-platform files. It's better to to remove a newline with a regex, because it always handles both cases.

After you joined every line, than you can split it again.

So your code could look like this:

```
# Remove newline at end of every line
s/\r?\n// for @data;

# join every line with whitespace
my $str = join " ", @data;

# split into tokens
my @tokens = split /\s+/, $str;
```

For example, to print 10 items on a line, you could use something like this. Full example:

```
my @data = <DATA>;

# Remove newline at end of every line
s/\r?\n// for @data;

# join every line with whitespace
my $str = join " ", @data;

# split into tokens
my @tokens = split /\s+/, $str;

# print 10 tokens on every line
my $counter = 0;
for my $token (@tokens) {
    print $token, " ";
    if ( ++$counter == 10 ) {
        print "\n";
        $counter = 0;
    }
}


__DATA__
TTAA 58231 63741
99823 15423 17003
70152 07604 29517
50586 04381 08513
40758 16182 11524
30967 31964 00510
25094 41365 25503
20241 53562 10512
15419 68542 07540
10656 76156 11024
88123 76950 09548
77999 31313 47708
82318=
```

But in my humble opinion, if you want to split everything by whitesapce, and ignore the lines, you could do it better, by just splitting every line, and push the result onto an array. Do it like this.

```
my @tokens;
for my $line (<DATA>) {
    push @tokens, split(/\s+/, $line);
}
```

One reason why i should change it this way is, that it is easier to work. And you also don't need to read the whole file, for example, you also could easily just insert the numbers into `@tokens` if you wish:

```
my @tokens;

for my $line (<DATA>) {
    # Extracts only numbers from a line
    my @vals = $line =~ m/\d+/g;
    push @tokens, @vals;
}
```

You can even further reduce everything just to.

```
my @tokens = map { m/\d+/g } <DATA>;
```

`map` executes the code-block for every array element. In this case for every line in `<DATA>` and puts the current line in the special variable `$_`. A regex on its own, matches on `$_` by default. `m/\d+/g` matches on `$_` and splits it into multiple elements, all of the elements from every line, go into `@tokens`.